# How to add new badge to general item in flutter?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, flutter, oop

I have flutter app with MySQL db, it has a list of items and i want to notify the user with the new added item with red circle or the new badge on it.

But the problem is that item is general and doesn't belong to that user only so i cannot say add 'is_read' column to that item and change from false to true.

What is the solution for this problem?
[image: new item]

Comment: you could save a setting in sharedpreferences that your item is read.

Answer (score 2):

try creating another table for what the user has checked,
with the columns: user_id, product_id.

and maybe add a time limit on it, so it won't get so big. so any product that's been available for more than a certain amount of time, won't be marked as "New" weather the user checked it or not, and you can delete it from the table if they did.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but how can i set time limit for that and what is the relation between user and product ( i think it has to be Many-To-Many)?